# MySQL: Putting single row results in seperate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL version 5.7.31, but just installed a MySQL server version 8 in case its needed

I have a table containing a range of information about an entity, like this:

```
+------+-----+  
| Name | Age |  
+------+-----+  
| Bob  |  22 |  
| Jack |  15 |  
| Jane |  25 |    
+------+-----+
```

In another table i have the information of which skills belongs to which combination of name and age like this:

```
+-------------+------+-----+  
|    Skill    | Name | Age |  
+-------------+------+-----+  
| programming | Bob  |  22 |  
| programming | Jane |  25 |  
| marketing   | Jane |  25 |  
+-------------+------+-----+
```

Which makes me able to select all skills for Jane, 25 - returning 2 rows. However i am required to put these into separate columns for each entity in a final view like below and i am struggling to figure out how to do this. The view should continue working when i get additional rows supplied in the tables shown above

```
+------+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+  
| Name | Age |   skill1    |  skill2   | skill3 |  
+------+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+  
| Bob  |  22 | programming | Na        | Na     |  
| Jack |  15 | Na          | Na        | Na     |  
| Jane |  25 | programming | marketing | Na     |  
+------+-----+-------------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: What MySQL version you have?

Comment: 5.7.17
Do i need to update to make this work?

Comment: Just upgraded it to 5.7.31 and i installed a version 8 aswell

Comment: By the looks of it, seems like a person can have at most 3 skills. Right? Apart from Programming and marketing what is the other skill a person might have in this case? And can you confirm there can be no other skills apart from these 3. Just Curious to know.

Comment: My problem has been solved by Gordon Linoff. But this is just an example showcasing the same problem i had in my task, but yes there was a fixed maximum amount of values to be put into the columns, which is also why i wanted a fixed amount of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these in separate columns in MySQL 5.7, probably the simplest method is correlated subqueries:

```
select p.*,
       (select ps.skill
        from person_skills ps
        where ps.name = p.name and ps.age = p.age
        order by ps.skill
        limit 1 offset 0
       ) as skill_1,
       (select ps.skill
        from person_skills ps
        where ps.name = p.name and ps.age = p.age
        order by ps.skill
        limit 1 offset 1
       ) as skill_2,
       (select ps.skill
        from person_skills ps
        where ps.name = p.name and ps.age = p.age
        order by ps.skill
        limit 1 offset 2
       ) as skill_3
from persons p;
```

This looks complicated, but the three subqueries are the same except for the `offset`.

Note:  This returns `NULL` rather than `'NA'` when no skills are available.  That is the typical way of representing an unavailable value.

If you really needed `'NA'`, you can use `COALESCE()`:

```
coalesce( (select ps.skill
           from person_skills ps
           where ps.name = p.name and ps.age = p.age
           order by ps.skill
           limit 1 offset 0
          ), 'NA') as skill_1,
```

An alternative in older versions is a hack using `group_concat()`:

```
select p.name, p.age,
       substring_index(group_concat(ps.skill order by ps.skill), ',', 1) as skill_1,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(ps.skill order by ps.skill), ',', 2), ',', -1) as skill_2,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(ps.skill order by ps.skill), ',', 3), ',', -1) as skill_3
from persons p left join
     person_skills ps
     on ps.name = p.name and ps.age = p.age
group by p.name, p.age;
```

This aggregates all the skills into a string and then extracts the *nth* element.

For `'NA'`, you would use `COALESCE()` like above.

Comment: I just installed a Mysql 8 server to try the other way (though its probably best in the old version, as i wont need to get MySql 8 server installed on my employers machine). If i were to use your suggestion and i needed the 'NA', it would be possible to include an IF statement somewhere in the view that returned 'NA' for null on these fields, right? Anyway thanks for the suggestion

Comment: The other suggestion did not work even with MySQL 8 as described in a comment to that suggestion. But yours works perfectly. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation. Say the tables are called `persons` and `person_skills`:

```
select p.name, p.age, 
    max(case when ps.rn = 1 then ps.skill end) skill1,
    max(case when ps.rn = 2 then ps.skill end) skill2,
    max(case when ps.rn = 3 then ps.skill end) skill3
from persons p
left join (
    select ps.*, row_number() over(partition by name, age order by id) rn
    from person_skills ps
) ps on ps.name = p.name and ps.age = p.age
group by p.name, p.age
```

It is unclear which logic you want to spread the skills over the columns. This assumes that you have an ordering column, called `id`, that can be used for this.

Comment: I'm a bit of a rookie in these complicated SQL-Queries. I get a syntax error with the left join after the select statement. Thank you very much for your reply.
  
The spread of the skills is irrelevant. They just just need to be in there, so another system can read them

Comment: "left" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

Comment: I can't make this work. I don't think it can, as the last select (ps) in your example knows which row it should have in the p table. Is it possible to something like row count, that counts how many different skills there are instead? So everytime the skill "programming" appears in the ps table, it has a field with the value 1, and everytime "marketing" appears it has a field with the value 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php) aggregation function for get comma separated list of skills:

```
select
    Users.Name,
    Users.Age,
    GROUP_CONCAT(Skill) AS Skills
from Users
left join Skills on Skills.Name = Users.Name
group by Users.Name, Users.Age
;
```

Here the fiddle [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d6c3fdb88d1d46dafe9f4b88fc44e162&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

**Result**

```
Name    Age    Skills
Bob     22     programming
Jack    15     NULL
Jane    25     programming,marketing
```

In case with limited skills count next query can be used:

```
select
    Users.Name,
    Users.Age,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(Skill='programming', 'programming', NULL)) AS Skill1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(if(Skill='marketing', 'marketing', NULL)) AS Skill2
from Users
left join Skills on Skills.Name = Users.Name
group by Users.Name, Users.Age
;
```

Fiddle [here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2a78c03f4d6362eff6e65abcae5ad06d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thank you very much (for fixing my question format aswell) and i have used that before. But in this specific case they need to be in seperate collumns

Comment: Du you know max skills count fro each user?

Comment: Yes i do --------

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you doing it fundamentally WRONG here, this is NOT how you should treat a relational database, it's borderline abusive.

Relational database lesson 101, ALWAYS use indexed autoincremented primary key. ALWAYS! (Sorry to be harsh but working in to many systems designed by people that don't understanding this basics making performance crazy bad).

This is how your user table should look like.

```
+----+------+-----+  
| id | Name | Age |  
+----+------+-----+  
|  1 | Bob  |  22 |  
|  2 | Jack |  15 |  
|  3 | Jane |  25 |    
+----+------+-----+
```

Skills table

```
+----+--------------+
| id | skill        |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | programming  |
|  2 | Marketing    |
+----+--------------+
```

Link table

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | skillId | userId |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      3 |
|  2 |       2 |      3 |
|  3 |       1 |      1 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

Okay now for the SQL itself, from your example it seems that you always want to have programing on skill1 and marketing as skill2, and in that case (we using max and group by to just get one row per user).

```
SELECT 
    u.name Name, u.age Age, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.id = 1 THEN s.skill ELSE NULL END) Skill1, -- Programmer 
    MAX(CASE WHEN s.id = 2 THEN s.skill ELSE NULL END) Skill2  -- Marketing
FROM 
    users u
LEFT JOIN 
    linktable l ON l.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN 
    skills s ON s.id = l.skillsId
GROUP BY 
    u.name, u.age
```

The best would obviously be to use `group_concat` as other has suggested but then you have to handle all the result in one column, but can handle unlimited number of skills.

```
SELECT 
    u.name Name, u.age Age, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill) Skills
FROM 
    users u
LEFT JOIN 
    linktable l ON l.userId = u.id
LEFT JOIN 
    skills s ON s.id = l.skillsId
GROUP BY 
    u.name, u.age
```

Comment: I know this and if i was working with a relational database as normal, i woulden't have the struggles i do. However this task required me to make a view that read data from tables (given to us by another company) and transform it into the described format for it to be read by another system.

Answer (score -1):

First Create table structure in such a way you can use definite condition... search more over **Pivot** options

Here is an example of such scenario

```
Create table Person (FName varchar(20), LName varchar(20), Age Int);

Insert into Person values 
('Jacke','W',29),
('Prince','P',30),
('Rush','B',29);


Create table Speciality (FName varchar(20), Skill varchar(20),Technology varchar(30));

Insert into Speciality values 
('Jacke','Skill1','Java'),
('Jacke','Skill2','Unix'),
('Jacke','Skill3','PHP'),
('Prince','Skill1','.Net'),
('Prince','Skill2','Python'),
('Prince','Skill3','Notepad++'),
('Rush','Skill1','Office 365'),
('Rush','Skill2','.Net');

select P.FName, p.LName, p.Age,
  MAX(IF(Skill = 'Skill1', Technology, NULL)) AS Skill1,
  MAX(IF(Skill = 'Skill2', Technology, NULL)) AS Skill2,
  MAX(IF(Skill = 'Skill3', Technology, NULL)) AS Skill3
from Person P, Speciality S
where P.FName=S.Fname
group by P.FName, p.LName, p.Age;

+--------+-------+------+------------+--------+-----------+
| FName  | LName | Age  | Skill1     | Skill2 | Skill3    |
+--------+-------+------+------------+--------+-----------+
| Jacke  | W     |   29 | Java       | Unix   | PHP       |
| Prince | P     |   30 | .Net       | Python | Notepad++ |
| Rush   | B     |   29 | Office 365 | .Net   | NULL      |
+--------+-------+------+------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but these "skills" and "persons", i get in a specific format, so i can't add a names like "skill1" and "skill2" to them. And i need to create a view, that can generate my result and it should work dynamically, so that when i get new "person" and "person-to-skill" rows (in the same format as previously) my view should be able to work on those aswell

Comment: At least my idea of adding category (skill1, skill2) gave someone clue how to group by and use it as datastore. hope you got your requested details... :0